# React control the order of text inputs in a form

Tags: reactjs

I have a form in react and according to configuration this form can have several inputs. The order of the inputs will also be controlled by the configuration.

This is my current code:

```
    const  login_fields = ["id","phone"];


    function IdInput() {
        if (login_fields.includes("id")) {
            return (
                <input  ref={idInput_ref} type="text" className="form-control" />
            )
        }
    }

    function PhoneInput() {
        if (login_fields.includes("phone")) {
            return (
                    <input  ref={phoneInput_ref} type="text" className="form-control" />
            )
        }
    }


    function ShowInputfields(){
        return (
            <>
            {(() => {
                login_fields.forEach((item, i)=>{
                    if(item==="phone") {return PhoneInput();};
                    if(item==="id") {return IdInput();};
                });
            })()}

            </>
        );      
    }
    
    return (
            <div>
                <form>
                    {ShowInputfields()}
                    <div>
                        <button id="login-submit">Submit</button>
                </form>
            </div>

    );
```

The configuration is const and it is held in `login_fields`.

Expected result in the case above is id field before the phone field.
(In real code there are more fields, for example name, email, etc).

Unfortunately the code doesn't work. I am getting the error:

```
Warning: unstable_flushDiscreteUpdates: Cannot flush updates when React is already rendering.
```

And no field is rendered on browser.

What should I change in order to achieve the desired outcome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change the `forEach` to a `map` and you also do not need to wrap it all in an anonymous function and call it.

so change `ShowInputfields` to
to

```
function ShowInputfields(){
  return (
    <>
      {
        login_fields.map((item, i)=>{
           if(item==="phone") {return PhoneInput();};
           if(item==="id") {return IdInput();};
        });
      }
    </>
  );
}
```

---

You also do not close the `<div>` before the `button`

Answer (score 1):

What you want is achievable but, a significant improvement will be required in your current coding pattern.

Consider creating a generalised Component, say, `InputField` that accepts the field to render as the `type` prop.
The responsibility of this component will include checking the `type` prop and then, returning the correct field.

After you follow the same, there will be no need to check the `login_field.include` inside every field component such as `PhoneInput`.

[image]

```
import React from "react";

// Assuming that Id and Phone Input are sufficiently distinct
// to justify creating separate components.
function IdInput() {
  return <input type="text" className="form-control" />;
}

function PhoneInput() {
  return <input type="text" className="form-control" />;
}

function InputField({ type }) {
  // Checking the type
  switch (type) {
    case "phone":
      return PhoneInput;
    case "id":
      return IdInput;
    default:
      return <input type="text" />;
  }
}

function CustomForm({ formFields }) {
  return (
    <form>
      {formFields.map((field) => (
        <InputField type={field} />
      ))}
      <button valu="submit" />
    </form>
  );
}
```